# How to export Lithuanian letters (ąčęėįšųūž) in PyFPDF?

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

Whenever I'm trying to generate a PDF with any Lithuanian letter (ąčęėįšųūž) I'm getting "UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0307' in position...". Tried adding a TTF font, locating my local Arial.ttf file, which when used in any other app works fine, however if used with PyFPDF it simply exports a blank text in place where the letters are used. Any way to export these letters?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import fpdf

pdf = fpdf.FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial", "B", 18)
pdf.set_xy(25, 25)
pdf.cell(w=160, h=10, align="C", txt="VAT Invoice")
pdf.set_font("Arial", "", 14)
pdf.cell(w=160, h=10, align="C", txt="SĄSKAITA ė")
pdf.output('./invoice.pdf', 'F')
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Also, which python version are you using? It looks like it's a problem with encodings, are you sure latin-1 is the enconding you want to be using in this case?

Comment: Looking at the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) for latin-1 encoding, it doesn't seem to have those letters that you mentioned in the title.

Comment: I added a sample code, which throws the error. I'm using Python 3.7.2. I've tried using utf8, however with no result still.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it should solve your problems: https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Unicode/index.html

Download a font that supports Unicode characters and follow the instructions on the site above. The code sample below assumes that you downloaded a DejaVuSans font (I got it from [here](https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/)).

```py
import fpdf

pdf = fpdf.FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.add_font("DejaVu", "", "DejaVuSans.ttf", uni=True)
pdf.set_font("DejaVu", "", 14)
pdf.cell(w=160, h=10, align="C", txt="SĄSKAITA")
pdf.output('./invoice.pdf', 'F')
```

Comment: Thanks @fulaphex! This one solved everything. Was using the wrong TTF file.